# Sql server bcp export binary in csv, How do I replace it with ''?"

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, export, bcp

I have a table that has an empty composition

[image]

when exporting it with bcp, it exports it in the following way; with the character "?"

```
bcp  table out table.csv -S local -U sa -d BD -c -t '|'
```

[image]

some solution to this problem, from bcp

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Brayan - there is no "?" in the file. I believe the "?" you see is just how your text editor is choosing to represent the ANSI "nul" character. If the file is going to be loaded into another SQL Server, you likely want the file to keep the ANSI "nul" in there. Before taking time to define a way to get rid of the "?" in the file, I'd first make sure you actually dont want the file to have an ANSI "nul" character in it. You mentioned a migration... from SQL Server to what? Another SQL Server? If so, then you definitely want to keep the ANSI "nul" in the file. They will load as empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and solved with

```
 -k
```

Hope it works for you too ;)

Well, of course it won't work... those field are set not to be NULL.
You should change that.
If you want the data still not to be NULL you should add a standard value for NULL elements from table

```
select case 
      when user_Name is null then "default value" 
      else user_name 
   end
```

Comment: some example please

Comment: If you want the table to display "NULL" you just need to use -k

Comment: remains the same, will it be because they are empty fields?

Comment: I don't want to offend you but.. did you set them as "NULL" in the database...I mean, can those values be NULL?

The -k is supposed to turn fields that can be null into "NULL" if they're empty

Comment: I did not build that bd and in the scheme that not null those fields

Comment: what is supposed to go inside those fields?
It could actually be a problem about data encoding

Comment: is a database that I was given to migrate, I can put it to accept null but I did not want to touch the database

Comment: Can you show me an example of what a data from PTCuadra looks like?
Are there any special signs that can't be red by the database?

Comment: I uploaded new images to document the best you can see it up

Comment: I extracted the sql and the PTcuadra field is ''

Comment: Well, of course it won't work... those field are set not to be NULL.
You should change that.
If you want the data still not to be NULL you should add a standard value for NULL elements



select case 
          when user_Name is null then "default value" 
          else user_name 
       end  
from table

Comment: Adding -k option to BCP is not the answer. Brayan's question was about bcp'ing data OUT of SQL Server. The -k option only applies to bcp "IN" operation and even then only invovles columns with defaults assigned.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
-c -C65001 -t -r"\n" -T -S;
```

or:

```
  -k
```